# Lecture/presentation/event: “conduct" vs. “carry out” vs. “hold”

Tags: single-word-requests

When talking about a lecture, presentation, or event, what verb should be used?

As far as I understand, any of *conduct*, *carry out*, or *hold* are possible here. What’s the difference, and which of them (if any) is the best option?

I’m particularly interested in something like this:

> Professor A is going to [***INSERT VERB***] a lecture about B next Thursday, February 14<sup>th</sup>.

Comment: Your request for best option is going to require substantially more context. "Conduct" and "carry out" suggest you are doing the actual lecture. "Carry out" is often used when someone else has given an order and you are the one executing the order, i.e., "carrying out" the order. "Hold" could be used even if you are only the sponsor or host, not the actual lecturer.

Comment: Or you could just use lecture as a verb, and skip all the trouble: Professor A is going to lecture about B next Thursday.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You give lectures and presentations. You can also deliver them. You hold an event if you organise it. You may conduct an experiment. You carry out some task.